# How to update object fields inside nested array and dynamically set a field value based on some inputs

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have been working on a Mongo database for a while. The database has some visits that have this form:

```
[
 {
    "isPaid": false,
    "_id": "5c12bc3dcea46f9d3658ca98",
    "clientId": "5c117f2d1d6b9f9182182ae4",
    "came_by": "Twitter Ad",
    "reason": "Some reason",
    "doctor_services": "Some service",
    "doctor": "Dr. Michael",
    "service": "Special service",
    "payments": [
        {
            "date": "2018-12-13T21:23:05.424Z",
            "_id": "5c12cdb9b236c59e75fe8190",
            "sum": 345,
            "currency": "$",
            "note": "First Payment"
        },
        {
            "date": "2018-12-13T21:23:07.954Z",
            "_id": "5c12cdbbb236c59e75fe8191",
            "sum": 100,
            "currency": "$",
            "note": "Second payment"
        },
        {
            "date": "2018-12-13T21:23:16.767Z",
            "_id": "5c12cdc4b236c59e75fe8192",
            "sum": 5,
            "currency": "$",
            "note": "Third Payment"
        }
    ],
    "price": 500,
    "createdAt": "2018-12-13T20:08:29.425Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-12-13T21:42:21.559Z",
}
]
```

I need to find some query to update some field of a single payment based on the _id of the visit and _id of the payment that is inside of nested array. Also when you update a payment's sum to some number so that the sum of all payments is greater than or equal to price the field isPaid is automatically updated to true.

I have tried some queries in mongoose to achieve the first part but none of them seem to work:

```
let paymentId = req.params.paymentId;
let updatedFields = req.body;

Visit.update(
{ "payments._id": paymentId },
{
  $set: {
    "visits.$": updatedFields
  }
}
).exec((err, visit) => {
if (err) {
  return res.status(500).send("Couldn't update payment");
}
return res.status(200).send("Updated payment");
});
```

As for the second part of the question I haven't really come up with anything so I would appreciate at least giving some direction on how to approach it.